# a question about the ELBO surgery in VAE

Tags: neural-networks, variational-bayes

In the paper "ELBO surgery: yet another way to carve up the variational evidence lower bound", Hoffman et al, propose to rewrite the ELBO, say $KL(q(z|x)||p(z))=KL(q(z)||p(z))+ I (x;z)$. In the derivation, they use $p(z|x_n)=p(z)$. I want to know why $p(z|x_n)=p(z)$. Anybody can help me?

Comment: Because the prior is independent of the data (?).

Comment: Yes, I just make it clear. $p(z)$ is the prior. In the paper, $p(n,z)$ is defined, not deduced.

Comment: So, in that case, the reason is that the prior is independent of the data. Only the posterior explicitly uses the data.

Comment: Yes, $p(n,z)$ is defined artificially. And $p(n,z)$ is not $p_{\theta}(n,z)$. I took $p(n,z)$ as $p_{\theta}(n,z)$ and got stuck.